# Run a Rails job at precise time (accurate to the second)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, sidekiq

I'm making an application that needs to run a job at extremely precise intervals of time (say 30 seconds, maximum acceptable delay is +-1 second).

I'm currently doing so using an external Go application that polls an API endpoint built within my application.

Is there a way that I could run the task on a worker machine (eg a Heroku dyno) with delays less than one second?

I've investigated Sidekiq and delayed_job, but both have significant lag and therefore are unsuitable for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schedule the job for 60 seconds prior to when you need it run. Pass in the exact time you need the job executed, as a parameter. Then, run `sleep` until `Time.now == exact_time_down_to_the_second`?

Comment: Great idea. I was thinking more along the lines of something built into the language but this sounds great. I'll accept this as the answer if nothing better comes along, primarily because I'm probably wasting cycles by calling sleep every now and then.

Comment: Yeah it is a little hackey but I think most scheduled jobs are extremely hard to ensure precision execution. I'd be very curious to hear if someone else has a better answer.